# Jquery is not working properly in asp.net AsyncPostBackTrigger

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

net.

Recently I have tried to validate some asp controls with my jquery functions in the content page.

Below I have given some code where i want to validate one dropdown list which will check that
the selected Index of the dropdown list is 0. If it is zero then the background of the dropdown list
will be red. Else it will remain same.

The other Control is TextBox. In the same way if the textbox's length is 0 then the backround color will 
be red.

When the save button will be clicked the validation will start.

Here I have given all the necessary code in jquery.

But the problem is when I click the Save Button then both Dropdown and Textbox turns red for a certain time(1 or 2 sec)
then turns into white background automatically.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"   runat="server">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var valid = 0;

        // check all fields validity when "Save" Button clicked
        $("#<%= btnSave.ClientID%>").bind("click", function () {
             var validity = validateAllFields();
             if (validity == false) {
                 return false;
             }
             else {
             }
         });
    });

    /// validating all fields
    // if all fields are valid then return true else return false//
    function validateAllFields() {
        var nValid = 0;
        //validate DropDown box
        nValid += checkDropdownList($("#<%= ddl1.ClientID%>")); // check ddl1 is Selected or not

        //validate Text Field
        nValid += checkTBLength($("#<%= tb1.ClientID%>"), 1); // check "tb1" length
        if (nValid > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

// check whether the dropdownlist is selected other than "Select Item"
// parametes- idDropdown= id the of the dropdown List
function checkDropdownList(idDropdown) {
    // check if the dropdown selected index is 0 or not
    // if zero then set the background color red
    if ($(idDropdown).prop('selectedIndex') == 0) {
        $(idDropdown).css("background-color", "red").trigger("change"); // set dropdownlist background color to red
        return 1;
    }
    else { // set the background color white
        $(idDropdown).css("border-color", "");
        return 0;
    }
}

/// check minimum required length of the textbox
// Parameters-  idTextbox= id of the textbox, minLength= minimum Required Length
function checkTBLength(idTextbox, minLength) {
    //check if the textbox's lenth is less than minimum Required Length or not
    if ($(idTextbox).val().length < minLength) {
        $(idTextbox).css("background-color", "red"); // set the background textbox color to red
        return 1; // return 1 for validation failed
    }
    else {
        $(idTextbox).css("background-color", "white");// set the background textbox color to red
        return 0; // return 1 for validation passed
    }
}

</script>


<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="true">Select</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

<div class="span4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Query Details</label>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="500" class="form-control" Rows="4" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" class="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Note that I have used AsyncPostBackTrigger in both controls.

Can you please mention why this is happening and how to resolve it.

Thank You.

Comment: <%= ddl1.ClientID%> this looks like server code, unless im mistaken JQuery cannot interpret this. If this isn't the problem could you post if you have an error or not and if so post the error please.

Comment: i couldn't understand your question properly. But for asp control which are runat server jquery can not catch direct id. that's why i have written i this way. As I have mentioned the controls turn red for a certain time(1 or 2 sec) then turns into white background automatically after 1 or 2 sec. i want the red background stay when the validation fail.

Comment: Ah ok no problem ill take another look.